# Arduino FFT library - Open Music Labs installation help

Tags: frequency, sound

I downloaded the zip file of the FFT library from the below link

http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/ArduinoFFT

and it now as I implement the example codes, it gives out a message which says
"Error compiling for Mega or Mega2560". 
I have an Arduino Mega2560 and I want to know how to use this library for my board for frequency analysis of sound. Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: How about sharing the rest of the error message?

Comment: E:\Setup files\arduino-1.6.10-windows\arduino-1.6.10-windows\arduino-1.6.10\libraries\FFT/FFT.h:181:3: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and string macro [-Wliteral-suffix]

   "ldi r16, "STRINGIFY(FFT_N/2)" \n" // prep loop counter

   ^


E:\Setup files\arduino-1.6.10-windows\arduino-1.6.10-windows\arduino-1.6.10\libraries\FFT/FFT.h:74:10: error: 'prog_int16_t' does not name a type

 PROGMEM  prog_int16_t _wk_constants[]  = {

          ^      These are the two types of errors being shown. Is there something wrong with the library? @Majenko

Comment: Works only on earlier versions of the IDE. That was the reason for the error.